# storing dictionary in session

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you create a dictionary of objects in the session? More specifically, I have a list of objects: MyList stores MyObject as the result of a linq query with the date as a parameter.

```
List<MyObject> Mylist;
MyList = GetObjects(TheDate);
```

Now I'd like to store MyList in the session object in a dictionary with the date as the key. When the page needs a MyList for a specific date, first search the dictionary and if it's blank for that date, get the data from the GetObjects query and store the result in the dictionary in the session.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried creating an object called MyDictio in a different file within a namespace called ObjectsSessions. When I try "public class Dictionary..." I'm not getting intellisense on the Dictionary keyword. Where do I declare this dictionary so that it's available in every page?

Comment: try `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: I already have this namespace in both the file that stores my objects (AppObjects.cs) and in the codebehind file of the corresponding aspx.

Comment: it shouldn't be `public class Dictionary<DateTime> MyDictio` - it should be `public Dictionary<DateTime> MyDictio`

Comment: I'm not getting intellisense on that either. Where does this declaration go?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sample for storing a dictionary in session:

```
List<MyObject> Mylist;
MyList = GetObjects(TheDate);
Dictionary<DateTime> myDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime>();
myDictionary[TheDate] = MyList;
Session["DateCollections"] = myDictionary;
```

Sample for retrieving from session (should have `null` check to be sure it's there):

```
Dictionary<DateTime> myDictionary  = (Dictionary<DateTime>) Session["DateCollections"];
```

Comment: ok, thanks! If I declare this dictionary in a code behind file, should I declare it in every code behind file of the app?

Comment: you need the retrieval part in every code behind file if you need to access the dictionary - the storing part you naturally only need when you want to create a new dictionary.

Comment: Is it a good idea to declare a dictionary in the master page? I'm thinking about creating 10 or so dictionaries of lists of objects.

Answer (score 5):

I would create some sort of facade around accessing Session variables, which makes retrieving and setting values very easy. Plus you don't have to worry about getting session var names correct as they are all stored in the same place. Example:

```
public static class SessionVars
{
     public static Dictionary<DateTime> DateCollections
     {
        get { return (Dictionary<DateTime>)HttpContext.Current.Session["DateCollections"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["DateCollections"] = value; }
     }
}
```

Then accessing it anywhere in your code would look like this:

```
  var List<MyObject> mylist = SessionVars.DateCollections[TheDate];
```

Comment: Note: This should handle null in the 'get'.  But I used a version of this in the end.