# declaring a session dictionary in a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

How do you declare a dictionary called MyDic in the master page?

I want MyDic to hold lists of objects MyObj with a date as the key so that I can write something like this: "get the list for date 1/28/2011 from MyDic" or "put this list of MyObj from 1/28/2011 in MyDic".

I'd like to declare the dictionary in the master page so that I can access it in every page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How were you planning on persisting the list? 
Instead of creating it in the master page, you could create it as an application variable, or if it is user-specific as a session variable. In either case you would do something like:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, myObj> myList = new Dictionary<DateTime, myObj>();
```

Then you would store it somewhere:

```
Session["MyList"] = myList;
```

and when you need to access it again:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, myObj> myList = (Dictionary<DateTime, myObj>)Session["MyList"];
```

You could do the declaration in the Master Page on init or on load, or even better i would suggest doing it in the global.asax file for either session or application

Comment: didn't I answer that very same question from you a few hours ago here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838129/storing-dictionary-in-session/4838354#4838354 ?

Comment: does this also work? Dictionary<int, List<ViewFolderModel> > SessionFolders = new Dictionary<int, List<ViewFolderModel> >(); Will this create a dictionary of lists?

Comment: get doesnt need to do .GetType()

Answer (score 2):

You can create a public property on Master page and then use it in content pages by setting **MasterType** Directive. e.g. if you have a Master Page named MyMasterPage then here is the code sample

```
/// declare it in Master Page
public Dictionary<DateTime, typeof(List<MyObj_Type>)> MyDic {
      get;
      set;
}

/// put the line just under Page directive on your content page where you want to access it

<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MyMasterPage.master"%>

/// and then on content page you can access by
** Note: The intelisense may not work but don't worry just put the code in content page and it works.**

Master.MyDic.Add(DateTime.Now, MyObj);
```

Here is details how [Accessing Members on the Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Have a good day!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) or [application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) variable for this kind of sharing.

This kind of scenario is pretty much what they were created for.

Comment: does this also work? Dictionary<int, List<ViewFolderModel> > SessionFolders = new Dictionary<int, List<ViewFolderModel> >(); Will this create a dictionary of lists?