# variable declared in master page not available in content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the master page code behind like this:

```
public partial class TheMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    string test = null;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
}
```

When I'm in the Page_Load function in the code behind of the content page, I don't see the variable test as being available. Am I declaring it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [declaring a session dictionary in a master page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839097/declaring-a-session-dictionary-in-a-master-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property should be public and should have get, set

```
public string test
{
    get; set;
}
```

I already answered it a little early [Accessing property of master page inside content page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839097/declaring-a-session-dictionary-in-a-master-page/4839322#4839322)

Answer (score 0):

Having a master Page is not the same as inheriting a page class.  What you would want to do is have a public property on the master page, and then access that from the content page.